# Indentation error in Python function

Tags: python, indentation

```
def parentMenu():
    for _num in menu1_list:
        print menu1_list
    prompt="Please Choose a sub menu"
    text1=raw_input(prompt)
    if text1 = 1:
       menu1_1()
    elif text1 =2:
       menu1_2()
    elif text1 =3:
       menu1_3()
    else:
       print "Incorrect!"
       parentMenu()
```

This code is giving a `unindent does not match any outer indentation level` error on the line where I have `if text1 =1:`.
If I indent that further with the others it says unexpected indent.

All this is suppose to be in the same function which is to display a menu and the user chooses 1, 2, 3.

Is the problem with the if statements appearing beneath `raw_input`? I haven't used user input before and wasn't sure what follows after it.

Comment: Are you mixing up spaces and tabs? Please check for that.

Comment: You should also correct your if conditions. The correct way to check for equality is to use `==`, like this `if text1 = 1:`. A single `=` is to assign values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Antimony. You are right, forgot about the ==, fixed that. Yes i guess i am confused with spaces and tabs. I'm using sublime text 3, which is setup for python, when i pressed enter after the first line for the function i just tried to follow that spacing. I believe after a line with : there needs to be spacing again. But im not sure on how much spacing. Rather confusing.  Would it be a bother to ask if you write my code out in proper spacing so i can follow how its suppose to be? would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 0):

I selected entire code of your function and from top menu selected,
 Format ->dedent region ad then just gave spaces whereever it was needed and I got this working correctly

```
def parentMenu():
    for _num in menu1_list:
     print (menu1_list)
     prompt="Please Choose a sub menu"
     text1=raw_input(prompt)
    if text1 == 1:
     menu1_1()
    elif text1 ==2:
     menu1_2()
    elif text1 ==3:
     menu1_3()
    else:
     print ("Incorrect!")
     parentMenu()
```

Comment: Thank you Shikha! that fixed it. Im more of a visual learner so seeing how something is suppose to be done helps more than information overflow.  I see above spaces is used more than indentation, i will read up more on when to use indentions rather spaces. When you said top menu selected, format -> dedent region. What were you referring to? At first i thought you meant in Sublime text IDE because i mentioned i was using that, but i dont see a Format option at the top. But i do have Python selected as the main syntax.